# Netbeans and Hibernate, import pojo and hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

The hibernate files(pojo's and hbm.xml) are in the web module of the project but I need this files in the ejb module too. 
How can I do the import?

Answer (score 0):

just move that to another project and use that as your "required project on the build path" for your EJBClient project

if you need more info about EJBClient find it [here](http://docs.jboss.org/ejbclient/1.0.5.Final/org/jboss/ejb/client/EJBClient.html) and [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.ejb.assembly.doc/topics/teclientjarcreate.html)